# Does use of Linux pread avoid "unavailability of data for reading written by a different thread"?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

Please assume below scenario (OS = Redhat Linux),

**Option A** :

***Writer Thread*** : Writes to a file using FD=1. Sets last written position and size in a std::atomic<int64_t> variable.

Edit for more clarity : write done using write C function call.
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html

***Reader Thread*** : Reads above file using a **different FD**=2 at value saved in above std::atomic<int64_t> variable.

Then **I presume** it is possible that, above read thread **NOT** being able to read all data written by the writer thread (i.e. a read call with FD=2 could return a lesser no of bytes). Since there could be buffering at FD level.

======================================================================================

**Option B:**

***Writer Thread*** : Writes to a file using FD=1. Sets last written position and size in a std::atomic<int64_t> variable.

Edit for more clarity : Only appends done (**no overwrite** takes place).write done using write C function call.
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html

***Reader Thread*** : Reads(using **pread**) above file using the **same FD**=1 at value saved in above std::atomic<int64_t> variable.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html

**Now, is it guaranteed that **ALL data** written by Writer thread **is read** by Reader Thread ?**

Comment: What about the case when the reader thread peeks at the value in the atomic, but right before it reads from its FD, the writer thread comes in and does another I/O operation?

Comment: If you _do_ `fflush` (as described in the correct answer), it won't matter at all which file descriptors you use: they're connected to the same inode and the same pages in the page cache. Only the internal libc buffers are separate, so that's what needs explicit flushing.

Comment: @Useless, Sorry if this was not clear. write done using write C function call.
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html, so fflush is NOT relevant in this case. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Buffering is at `libc` level, keeping the data around before handing it over to the kernel. `pread` is a syscall, it will only give you the data that has already been shown to the kernel.

So no. `pread` saves you the extra calls for seek+read, it does not solve any buffering issues.

How can you ensure that the kernel gets to see your data? You haven't shown your writer code, but usually calling `fflush` should do it.

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear. write done using write C function call.
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html, so fflush is NOT relevant in this case. I have edited the question.

Comment: Then you may also want to clarify what you mean by "buffering at FD level". Once the kernel gets your data, it maintains a consistent view of it to everyone whether it is in RAM or written to disk.Write may not be instantaneous and atomic (partial write? EINTR?) but using `pread` does not solve that either.

Comment: What I meant by "buffering at FD level" was, I thought (just a speculation), when writing with write call for a particular FD, kernel might maintain a buffer at FD level. Atomic variables I mentioned are updated only if the write is successful (i.e. written position and written data size is stored).

Comment: You can rest assured then. Per-FD kernel-level buffering that would make the same data visible through some syscalls but not others is not a thing.

Comment: Does this mean both above Option A and Option B, can guarantee availability of all data in reader thread ?